# Extra blank lines in markdown file after submitting and saving in Django

Tags: python, html, django, file, markdown

I have a problem with saving information submitted by the user. One of my website's pages should have a textarea for markdown text. Data entered by the user in this area should be saved in a separate file after submitting. But when I open saved file after submitting, there are extra blank lines. Functions from views.py and HTML form are presented below.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage


def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        save_data(request.POST.get("title"), request.POST.get("content"))   
    return render(request, "my_app/page.html")


def save_data(title, content):
    filename = f"files/{title}.md"
    if default_storage.exists(filename):
        default_storage.delete(filename)
    default_storage.save(filename, ContentFile(content))
```

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="title">Enter a title:</label><br>
    <input id="title" type="text" name="title">
    <br><br><label for="textarea">Enter the information:</label><br>
    <textarea id="textarea" name="content"></textarea><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Page">
</form>
```

If I try, for example, to type in the textarea the following text:

```
# My file

This is markdown file.
This file was created as an example for my question.
```

I see this after submitting:

```
# My file



This is markdown file.

This file was created as an example for my question.
```

Could you help me solve this problem, please? Thank you in advance!

---

Problem solution:

OK, the essence of the problem becomes clear if you try to use `print(repr(request.POST['content']))`. After execution this command you will get `# My file\r\n\r\nThis is markdown file.\r\nThis file was created as an example for my question.`. So, the problem is the difference in new line encoding in Windows and Linux/Mac OS. Read more in the answer below.

Comment: Might be the new line encoding. If you perform a hexdump it might be `\r\n`, what is the result of `print(repr(request.POST['content']))`?

Comment: @Willem, sorry, I couldn't answer immediately because I'm not familiar with hexdump, so I went to read about it. As I understand, hexdump is a linux command, but I don't use linux

Comment: yes, I already had that idea, can you work with `print(repr(request.POST['content']))`?

Comment: @Willem, '# My file\r\n\r\nThis is markdown file.\r\nThis file was created as an example for my question.'

Comment: yes, this also makes it easy for people in the future, and then I can remove the downvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to me like a difference in how new lines are encoded. Indeed, Windows uses a [*carriage return* (`\r`) <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) and then a [*line feed* (`\n`) <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode), whereas Linux and Mac OS X use a line feed (`\n`) only. Now often certain systems will then also interpret this as a new line. But this is *rendering*, not the *content*. Likely the editor in which you look at the file has set the line endings on `\n` or LF or Linux.

You can however clean the input before saving it with:

```
def index(request):
    if 'title' in request.POST and 'content' in request.POST:
        save_data(
            request.POST['title'], request.POST['content'].replace('\r\n', '\n')
        )
    return render(request, "my_app/page.html")
```

---

> **Note**: Please use `request.POST['content']` over `request.POST.get('content')`. Using `.get(…)` often only silences the error, but not the problem: indeed it will work if the key is missing. But if the value for that key is really required, it will only result in more trouble later in the process.